# XCode Instruments Warning - "Insufficient task_for_pid privileges (LeakAgent)"

Tags: xcode4.2, ios-simulator, xcode-instruments, memory-leak-detector

While running Instruments I get the warnning "Insufficient task_for_pid privileges (LeakAgent)", after that Instruments doesn't show the time chart for Leaks

can anyone point me in the right direction to solve this issue?

I'm building for iOS 3.0 on iOS simulator 5.0, using Base SDK 5.1 without any code signing, on Xcode 4.2

My app is not trying to access any authorization service of function AFAIK, only reading some information from the application bundle and parsing it into Graphics elements using the library Cocos2d-X

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `LeakAgent` is the process Instruments uses for periodically checking for leaks.

When I started Instruments the first time, it asked me for my administrator password. Did it ask you for that?

If not, you could try just restarting your computer, or deleting the Instruments preferences plist? `~Library/Preferences/com.apple.Instruments3.plist` (just guessing it may then re-prompt for admin permissions?)

Comment: hmm, the first time I executed Instruments Leak Agent, certainly it prompted me for admin password, and I given my admin pass.

I tried renamming com.apple.Instruments3.plist, but Istruments didn't promt for credentials, neither leak agent showed any warnings, weird

Answer (score 1):

@DouglasHeriot's answer didn't helped me. So I've just launched Instrumets via `sudo` from Terminal: `sudo /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/MacOS/Instruments`.

May this will be of help for somebody.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same issue, It took me almost 2 days to resolve the issue. Finally got the solution. Make sure that your profile scheme is in DEBUG mode instead of RELEASE. This will solve the issue.